# jquery show/hide - start open if condition true

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

Working on a jQuery show hide box for filter checkboxes on my MVC3 razor page.

I have a page which changes depending on whether these checkboxes are checked or not, but I'd like them to stay open if any of the checkboxes are unchecked.

Currently the show/hide works, but how do I determine whether the page loads with them shown/hidden based on if any checkboxes are checked?

I can return a boolean value to state if any are unchecked or not, and was really looking for a jQuery genius to help me with the best/tidiest way to achieve this.

Here is an example of one of the filters, where modeFilterList is a generic list for each checkbox, containing the name, ID and checked status:

```
<div id="filterwrap">
    <h2 class="filter">Filter your results</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <ul id="filter">
        <li>
            <h2>                            
                <a href="#">Modes</a></h2>
            <div class="filtercontent">
                @foreach (var item in modeFilterList)
                {
                    <div class="radiorow">
                        @Html.CheckBox("mode_" + item.ID, item.Checked)
                        @item.Name
                    </div>
                }   
            </div>
            <!-- end of filtercontent -->
        </li>
    </ul>
    }
</div>
```

This is the jquery code for showing and hiding:

```
$('#filterwrap li h2').live('click', function (e) {
    $(this).next('div.filtercontent').slideToggle() ;
    e.preventDefault();  //stops page jumping to top
});
```

I thought about having a hidden field containing a true/false value just below the h2 that could be read when the page reloads, but there must be a nicer way to do it with jQuery!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, not crazy about the solution I've come to, so if anyone has anything better and tidier, let me know.

So, for each filter, I pass a bool parameter via viewbag to show if any checkboxes have been selected.

```
bool modeStatus = ViewBag.modeStatus;
```

I then added a hiddenfield with class:

```
<div id="filterwrap">
    <h2 class="filter">Filter your results</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <ul id="filter">
        <li>
            @Html.Hidden("mode", modeStatus, new { @class = "filteritem" })
            <h2>                            
                <a href="#">Modes</a></h2>
            <div class="filtercontent">
                @foreach (var item in modeFilterList)
                {
                    <div class="radiorow">
                        @Html.CheckBox("mode_" + item.ID, item.Checked)
                        @item.Name
                    </div>
                }   
            </div>
            <!-- end of filtercontent -->
        </li>
    </ul>
    }
</div>
```

and this code within the (document).ready

```
$("input.filteritem:hidden").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "True") {            
        $(this).nextAll('div.filtercontent').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Jquery toggle() function or $("componentID").show() or hide() function

Comment: Thanks Uttesh.  The show hide part does work, but I'll look to tidy the code up.  What I'm really looking for though is to determine whether each one should load up first on the page shown or hidden depending on if any checkboxes within each section are checked?

Comment: I've updated the code above to use slideToggle, instead of adding and removing classes.  Good suggestion, thanks.  Will keep looking for solution to my query about the toggle status on page load.